# ¿Cómo se distinguen los "cereales" del desayuno de las gramíneas?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras

La palabra cereal, o cereales, define:

- *gramíneas, herbáceas cuyos granos o semillas están en la base de la alimentación* ([Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cereal)).
- de forma usual, lo que se come en un tazón de leche cada mañana.

Por tanto, si decimos "quiero comer cereales" entendemos que queremos tomar algún tipo de cereal procesado para mezclar con leche, y no, por ejemplo, un platazo de arroz.

Sin embargo, ¿hay alguna forma de denominar a este componente del desayuno de una forma única e inequívoca?

Comment: En mi opinión, lo único que se me ocurre sería denominar el cereal correspondiente por su nombre específico.  Eg.: 'Quiero comer Kellog's' o cualquier otra marca de cereal.

Comment: "Cereales **de desayuno**"? "Copos de maíz o trigo inflado, cubiertos con miel y/o azúcar"? Por cierto que el Dr. Kellog los ideó como una especie de antiafrodisiaco entre otras cosas. El tipo era además [gran promotor de la circuncisión](http://www.historyofcircumcision.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=48&Itemid=0) para evitar la masturbación e incluso ["tratamientos" que iban un paso más lejos](http://mentalfloss.com/article/32042/corn-flakes-were-invented-part-anti-masturbation-crusade). Y de ahí vienen nuestros cereales, de un intento de que nos _tocáramos_ menos.

Comment: @Diego maaaadre mía, ¡vaya personaje! No sabía nada de todo esto, las lecturas me han resultado interesantísimas : ) Por cierto, me gusta la sugerencia de *cereales de desayuno*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La comunicación entre dos personas incluye un emisor, un receptor y un contexto.

Dependiendo de estos 3 factores puede darse lugar a interpretaciones y cambios de significado. Sin embargo siendo nativo de Latinoamérica no puedo imaginarme ningún contexto en el cual alguien diga `Quiero desayunar cereales` y otra persona le pregunte `¿Quieres que te traiga un plato de arroz?`

Si la respuesta que buscas es si "existe una manera inequívoca" pues sí existe. Tienes que decir una frase mas larga explicando específicamente la clase de cereales que quieres para eliminar la ambigüedad del contexto.

> Quiero comer para el desayuno una mezcla de cereales que incluya
>   hojuelas de maíz tostado, cebada, avena y trigo.

Pero es obvio que esto suena ridículo.

Si estando de viaje por latinoamerica te preguntan `¿Qué quiere desayunar?` y contestas `Cereales` te aseguro que no te van a traer un plato de arroz. Ahora, es posible que te traigan hojuelas de maíz azucaradas o Granola (normalmente con algo de fruta) y si tienes preferencia por una u otra nuevamente tendrás que ser mas especifico en tu respuesta.

Espero que esto te ayude.